# Refresh a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, refresh

Is possible refresh a function every x seconds or refresh it on single event?

I will explain:

I have a function that makes pagination on my website, inside every div that are "pages" I have some pictures where I have added LightBox.

Everything works nice on the first div (page) but when I change the page it doesnt' work anymore.

I tried to fix in this way:

```
$('.pagination a').click(function () {
    initShadow();
});
```

In this way it work on the pageLoad and on the first page that I change, than it stop again.

So I need to fix this issue, everytime I change the "page" I would like it works fine.

Is possible to refresh a function every x second or to refresh it everytime I click on the pagination buttons?

Comment: Is there one pagination button, or you have one on every page?

Comment: are these 'pages' being loaded in via ajax? or being built dynamically after the page has already loaded?

Comment: is a pagination, alot of pages... in everypage I want shadowbox (or other plugIns) to work...

Comment: @jondavidjohn is not loaded via Ajax, just simple jQuery/css

Comment: can we see the pagination code?

Comment: I used this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) is what you are looking for.  If you want to take the timed route.

```
setInterval(functionToExecute, 1000); 
//this would call 'functionToExecute' every 1000 milliseconds
```

Otherwise, I would recommend using `.live()` instead of `.click()` just incase your pagination links are being removed and recreated by the plugin.  Thought this might be the case when you said it worked 1 additional time after you added this click event.

example

```
$('.pagination a').live('click',function () {
    initShadow();
});
```

Comment: can you please extend this example?

Comment: I've fixed it so it will: you need to pass the name of the function to be executed, without the () in order to get it to be called every <interval>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.on()` method of jQuery.

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function () {
    initShadow();
});
```

Hope this helps.